# MySQL query for content UP TO a certain string and AFTER same string

Tags: php

In a query result, I want to store everything leading UP TO a certain string, the `</a>` in `<a href="imgpath" imgsrc="imgpath"></a>` and then everything AFTER the `</a>` to a second variable.

[edit] a rephrasing of the question:

the value in $row[post_content] would be something like `"<ahref=''><image></a><p>copy</p>" ...`

i need to split this into `$val1 = "<ahref=''><image></a>"; and $val2 = "<p>copy</p>";`

This is probably done with `substr()`? but i have no idea how, and I HAVE searched, and found nothing but references to bad character sets in mysql because of my use of the term 'character' in my search.

Comment: What if you have many ending tags `</a>` in the same string ?

Comment: right, i just want to separate at the first one. the rest will be text links, and i'll probably lop the stuff off at 25 words anyway.

Comment: What probably you want is `spliting the string with delimiter as </a>`. Mysql doesn't have one built in but you can create UDF for the same. Check this link. http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Comment: oh my gosh (i WON'T write 'omg'), can't i just do it with php? maybe i didn't word the question correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$tmp = explode('</a>', $yourStr);
print_r($tmp);
```

You tagged your question with mysql, so Bohemian gave you answer using mysql. Please use correct tags and description to get right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will do it, assuming `val` is your column name:

```
select
    substr(val, 1, instr(val, '</a>') + length('</a>') - 1) as part1,
    substr(val, instr(val, '</a>') + length('</a>')) as part2;
```

Here's a test:

```
set @val := 'one<a href="imgpath">two</a>three';

select
    substr(@val, 1, instr(@val, '</a>') + length('</a>') - 1) as part1,
    substr(@val, instr(@val, '</a>') + length('</a>')) as part2;
```

Comment: thanks, Bohemian - my mistake all the way, i realize that this is really more of a php question.